# react-i18next can't translatete rendered object

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I am trying to translate my portfolio page with react-i18next but even though I looked into many related questions here I just can't get it to work.

I'm using a map function to render an object but couldn't get it's translation to work.

```
{projetos.map((projeto) => (
            <div className="col-md-6 col-lg-3 card bg-transparent" key={projeto.id}>
              <img src={projeto.image} alt="" className="img-fluid galeimg card-img border border-4 border-success rounded-4" />
              <div className="card-img-overlay cardcontent">
                <h5 className="card-title h4">{projeto.title}</h5>
                <p className="card-text h5">{projeto.text}</p>
                <p className="card-text">{projeto.text2}</p>
                <a href={projeto.link} target="_blank" className="btn btn-success">Ver</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
```

The objects are in the Projetos.jsx file. I loaded the repo here: https://codesandbox.io/p/github/caiourtiga/zport/main

How can I solve this and also add the rest of my site's text in the Projetos.jsx file? Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

I tried solutions from other questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71449362/how-to-iterate-i18n-array-of-objects-in-react-app), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61805309/how-to-translate-data-in-array-of-objects-with-map-using-react-i18next?rq=3) and others) but couldn't get it to work.

Edit: I solved it, will post solution soon.

Comment: could you set the codesandbox public

Comment: My bad, it is public now @Liap

Comment: I can't see any i18next.js or its relavant config file in your project and you are also fethcing data directly from projetos there is nothing configured with i18next.

Comment: Yes, I purged almost everything and am waiting for suggestions while trying to make it work locally